# How to resolve merging conflicts when working with mq in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, revision

Context: Mercurial with `mq` extension enabled

Let's say you have a patch but before pushing the changes, you want to make sure that you have the latest and greatest version.

You will pop your patch - `hg qpop`, pull and update changes - `hg pullup` and push the patch - `hg qpush <patchName>`.

When you try to push the patch, you have conflicts. Instead of having a merging tool popping up (meld, kdiff3, etc), all the conflicted classes are now added into the working folder with the .rej extension and the **patch is not applied**.

Is there any way to have the conflict resolution tool popping up instead of .rej files?

Comment: Why is this tagged with git? I see nothing related to git here

Comment: You could try the `rebase` extension and use `hg pull --rebase` instead of `qpop/pull/qpush`.

Comment: You are right that has nothing to do with git  taylorc93.  I updated the tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process to update a patch queue with using a 3-way merge is explained in the hgbook, chapter 12, §Updating your patches when the underlying code changes:
http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html#sec:mq:merge

If you are slightly more daring, you might also consider to look at the (still experimental) mutable history extension of mercurial which solves these issues much more conveniently by using obsolescence markers.